# What's the best way to get the next 7 day names in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to do a function that behaves as below:

```
getNext7Days()
// if today is monday it will return: ['Monday', 'Tuesday',...,'Sunday']
// if today is tuesday it will return: ['Tuesday', Wednesday',...,'Monday]
```

I am looking for a better solution with es6 or momentjs rather than doing a loop adding one day to current date and getting the day name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No library solution:

```
let days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
let today = new Date().getDay(); // Sunday is 0
return days.slice(today).concat(days.slice(0, today));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Date.prototype.getDay` returns the day of the week as a number where `0` is Sunday, which makes a convenient index into an array:

```js
const DAYS = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

function next7Days(date = new Date()) {
  const today = date.getDay();
  return DAYS.slice(today).concat(DAYS.slice(0, today));
}

console.log(next7Days());
// => ["Sunday", "Monday", ... "Saturday"]
console.log(next7Days(new Date(2020, 0, 1)));
// => ["Wednesday", "Thursday", ... "Tuesday"]
```